# Custom scrollviewer template scroll button

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, scrollviewer

I have been working on an issue where I want a scrollviewer whose scroll bar is replaced with a button to scroll left and a button to scroll right. (seperate buttons in different grid locations), however I have been struggling to get my head around it as the scrollviewers quite a complicated control.

Lets say I am creating a new control template for scrollviewer and I want to add an extra button into the template that would scroll the content to the right. How would I hook into the command that moves the horizontalscrollbar right. For example my code might have the following scroll bar and buttons and I want to hook into "horizontalscrollbars" right scroll button.

```
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                    Minimum="0"
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                                    ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                                    />

                        <Button Grid.Column="0"
                                x:Name="LeftBtnScroll">                    
                        </Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2"
                                x:Name="RightBtnScroll">
                        </Button>
```

p.s I don't have access to blend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably won't like this answer, but you'll also have to define a `ControlTemplate` for the `Scrollbar` element as well... that is the element that has the `Button`s that move the content. You can find the default `ControlTemplate` for the `Scrollbar` on the [ScrollBar Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278076%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

On that page, you'll see a section called *ScrollBar Parts*. This details the named parts of this `ControlTemplate`. A named part is an element that the 'code behind' accesses to provide some functionality. When defining a new `ControlTemplate`, you must include these named parts, or some (or maybe all) of the functionality will not work as expected.

The `Button`s in the `ScrollBar` are the named parts that are of type `RepeatButton`. However, using this method, you will only be able to define your own version of those `RepeatButton`s and not add additional ones. The functionality that actually moves the content comes from the [`IScrollInfo` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and have not been exposed by the `ScrollBar` control, so you cannot hook additional `Button` clicks to them.

Failing that, the alternative is even longer... you'll need to define your own custom scroll panel that implements the `IScrollInfo` interface. In doing this, you can then provide your own custom scroll functionality and arrange everything exactly the way that you want:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll=”True”>
    <YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourCustomPanel>
        <!--Your Content-->
    </YourXmlNamespacePrefix:YourCustomPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This operation is explained beautifully in chapter 7 of the WPF Control Development Unleashed book... you can find a PDF copy online at http://www.adorkable.us/books/wpf_control_development.pdf. It's well worth a look.

[UPDATE 27/11/2014: Sorry, this link is now broken... you'll have to buy the book to see it now.]

Comment: Thanks, Ill probably go down the route of defining a scrollbar element. I'm wondering how I am going to separate the two buttons though.. I presume I would have to make two separate templates for the scroll bar for each respective button...

Comment: Yes, if you look at the first linked page, you'll see a number of `ControlTemplate`s that have been defined for the various parts of the `ScrollBar`.